# Why is monster index still going strong?

Tags: economy, trade, finances, creature-design

An index is a measure of how a stock market is performing.  Even the monsters know how to build up their portfolio.

When a kill is secured -- say a human being -- or a carcass is recovered, they are cut up into many pieces and have their blood completely drained, then these parts will be distributed among the shareholders...so far still with me?

So basically, they will trade these mutilated pieces among themselves, and occasionally, they will also offer performance shares, meaning free of charge, no obligation like a boss!

They would even accept bones in exchange for meats etc., so that the weaker ones will have to dig the grave if need be.

Now that humans clearly have the upper hand, using their cunning tactics and innovation to design better weaponry and traps to protect themselves against the monsters -- how can the monster index still growing strong?

Comment: A stock market or its index can only exist if thee is some form of monetization behind it. What is the monetization of these monsters? How do they compute 'monetized value'?

Comment: @JustinThyme: substitute federal reserve bone with dollar note, listed clan with company so instead of owning a portion of the company gathering more teeth allows the monster to gain higher social status with the respective clan ;D

Comment: Haha actually I like to have a different approach to stock market or crowdfunding if you like so any suggestions as long as it protray monster behaviour and psychology...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scarcity driven market. If the demand stays the same, but the availability of the traded good diminishes, the price of the good will go up, and so will the margins for those  who manage to secure a delivery.

It happens with shoes, clothes, cars, phones, immaterial services, whatever can have a price attached to it.

Why would the MIT (Monster Indexed Trading) be any different?

Answer (score 4):

A breeding program.

Some monster is going to figure out where new humans come from and have an idea, "what if I keep some and make more?". That way you can bypass the hunting part, and most humans will gladly try to create their own food.

You could perhaps give them a religion to keep them docile. Teach the children that monsters are higher beings that will eventually take the body apart and bring the soul to their God and they would even go (somewhat) willingly to their own slaughter.

Answer (score 3):

**Human cunning tactics**

The monster index is being driven up by trades seemingly by ordinary monsters, but actually secretly coordinated by a cabal of humans using monster accounts.  The humans will take profits and then bail out, causing the monster index to crash and wiping out monster wealth.